# How to show quick settings menu on lock screen

Tags: lock-screens, quick-settings, resurrection-remix-os

I'm using resurrection remix LP v-5.5.9 custom rom on Lenovo tb3-710i android 5.1.1.
When I try to open the quick settings menu on lock screen by swiping down, it doesn't appear. I want to be able to change the brightness or connect to the internet, but without showing notifications. How can I do this?